# Сравнение двух файлов и запись разницы в третий файл в цикле python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сравнить файлы в двух папках, названия у этих файлов одинаковое, различается только содержимое этих файлов. После сравнения мне нужно оставить только разницу между двумя файлами и записать её в файл с тем же именем, как у сравниваемых, например:

Файл **text1.txt** из папки folder1

```
text1
text2
```

Файл **text1.txt** из папки folder2

```
text1
text2
text3
```

На выходе хочу получить файл **text1.txt** в папку folder3 с уникальным содержимым

```
text3
```

На выходе получается, что есть три папки и в каждой из них одинаковое количество файлов(в folder3 файлы могут быть пустые), только в folder3 внутри файлов остается только разница между файлами из двух других папок

Моя реализация задачи:

```py
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(old_path, '*.po')):
    po_file = polib.pofile(file)
    for i in po_file:
        old_texts[i.msgid] = i.msgstr


for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(new_path, '*.po')):
    po_file = polib.pofile(file)
    for i in po_file:
        new_texts[i.msgid] = i.msgstr


# оставляем только новые строки при сравнении двух файлов
diff_po_file = {k: new_texts[k] for k in set(new_texts) - set(old_texts)}
```

Сейчас у меня происходит запись уникальных текстов из двух папок в один общий файл:

```py
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for key, value in diff_po_file.items():
        f.write('msgid "{}"\nmsgstr "{}"\n\n'.format(key, value))
```

Как можно реализовать запись уникальных текстов в файл с таким же именем, какое было при сравнении, как это показано в примере?

**UPD:**
Либо как вариант сделать проверку на наличие разницы между файлами чтобы не оставлять пустые файлы, например(псевдокод):

```py
if diff_po_file:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for key, value in diff_po_file.items():
            f.write('msgid "{}"\nmsgstr "{}"\n\n'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: А как из содержимого первого файла "text1text3" и содержимого второго файла "text1 text2 text3" вам удалось получить "text3"  -  это копия данных вашего вопроса.

Comment: опечатка, сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу следующим путем:

1. Разбил задачу на функции (чтение, дифф, запись)
2. При чтении идет запись данных из файла в словарь (в моем случае)
3. Дифф между двумя словарями (один на каждый файл) с помощью множеств, как в самом вопросе
4. Записал полученный дифф в файл с таким же именем, как в п.1
5. Добавил сие творение в цикл

```py
def read_file(filename):
    texts = {}
    po_file = polib.pofile(filename)
    for i in po_file:
        texts[i.msgid] = i.msgstr
    return texts


def diff_files(file1, file2):
    f_1 = read_file(file1)
    f_2 = read_file(file2)
    content = {k: f_2[k] for k in set(f_2) - set(f_1)}
    return content


def write_file(filename, content):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for key, value in content.items():
            f.write('msgid "{}"\nmsgstr "{}"\n\n'.format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Как можно реализовать запись уникальных текстов в файл с таким же
>   именем, какое было при сравнении, как это показано в примере?*

--  Исправить логику программы. Сейчас вы вообще нигде (я по крайне мере не вижу где) проверяете "одинаковость" имен первого и второго файла.

Не ясно, может-ли быть ситуация, когда имена в ваших первой и второй папке не совпадают? Надо-ли это проверять?

Предположим, что не надо, т.е. имена файлов в фолдерах одинаковы.
Тогда логика должна быть следующая:

> - глобальный цикл просматривает все файлы первой папки последовательно.
>
>   - для каждого файла открывается он сам (на четние), файл с таким-же именем из 
>       второй папки (на чтение)  и  файл с тем-же именем в третьей папке (на запись), 
>       если последнего нет - он создается.
>   - выявляются уникальные элементы (это у вас написано)
>   - полученные уникальные элементы записываются в третьий файл.
>   - все три файла закрываются.

Если же в папках  могут быть файлы с несовпадающими именами - надо брать пересечение этих имен и работать только с файлами, попавшими в это пересечение. Исправление коснуться начальной части алгоритма.

Перевести на Python, надеюсь, сможете самостоятельно.

Comment: Имена файлов всегда совпадает, поэтому проверку на "одинаковость" не делал

Comment: @swede001   А  остальное?

Comment: не совсем понял, что имеется в виду под "остальным"
думаю попробовать сделать сначала так, разбить на функции:
1. чтение двух файлов
2. сравнение этих файлов
3. запись третьего файла (разницы)

Comment: @swede001 Вы не поняли алгоритм, который я вам написал выше?

Comment: А, алгоритм я понял, спасибо!

Comment: Списибо тут выражают немного по другому

Comment: Репутация не позволяет отметить Ваш ответ полезным, точнее голос не будет отображаться

Comment: Но принять решение, вы кажется можете. Впрочем - не важно