# Сравнение двух директорий с последующим удалением несовпадений (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия, сравнение, удаление

Приветствую сообщество ru.stackoverflow! Помогите, уже изломал себе голову как реализовать.

Есть, например папки: 'D:\лево' и 'С:\право'.

В них содержимое: файлы, директории с файлами, поддиректории, поддиректории с файлами. Большая часть содержимого одинаковая, однако в 'С:\право' может быть 'лишнее' содержимое (не совпадающая с содержимым 'D:\лево').

Как можно сравнить содержимое (что есть в) 'С:\право', чего нет в 'D:\лево' и после это (лишнее в 'С:\право')  удалить, чтобы папки 'D:\лево' и 'С:\право' стали идентичны (в нашем случае не смотрим на размер, время и т.д - чисто по именам их содержимого).

Пробовал вот так для выведение лишнего:

```
diferent = list(set(os.path.join(right, f) - set(os.path.join(left, f)))
```

Но этого мало, ведь оно не распространяет эффект на поддиректории.

Еще вот так:

```
from dirsync import sync
sync(left, right, 'diff')
```

Но, там меня интересует только 1/3 от вывода и как именно пустить этот вывод под удаление для меня дремучий лес.

Удалять все с 'С:\право', чтобы перекопировать с 0-ля 'D:\лево' в 'С:\право' - это не решение.

Я уверен, что решение зациклено на

```
os.walk
```

Но хоть убейте никак не могу выстроить верно

Большое спасибо заранее за любую помощь и прошу прощение за глупость.

Прикрепляю скриншоты:

Вход:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим так же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желаемый результат после выполнения программы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробовал показать в скриншотах на окнах для наглядности

Comment: На сайте уже был аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108775/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-python

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий. Но у меня всё же немного другой вопрос, ведь ''содержимое файлов" не интересует - интересует содержимое директорий и последующая работа с содержимым в одной из директорий (а именно удаление).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое спасибо 'Riccardo Bucco' c stackoverflow.com за его ответ. С его помощью все удалось как нельзя лучше:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import os

pl = Path(left_way) # left_way = r'D:\left' = 'D:\\left' 
pr = Path(right_way) 
difference = (set(map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pr), pr.rglob('*'))) - set(
    map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pl), pl.rglob('*')))) # pathlib сила!

if len(difference) > 0:
    print('\nContent to be deleted:\n')
    for a in difference:
        a2 = Path(pr, a)
        print('   ', a2)
     while True:
        copyornot = input('\nDelete? (Y/n):\n')
        if copyornot == 'Y':
            break
        elif copyornot == 'n':
            print('...')
            continue
        else:
            print('(Y/n)')
    
    for a in difference:
        a2 = Path(pr, a)
        if os.path.isfile(a2):
            os.remove(a2)
        if os.path.isdir(a2):
            shutil.rmtree(a2)
    print('\nFinish')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]